# Call the method of the super class in an other method of the subclass

Tags: python, subclassing

I already asked about something related to the game I am developing. The Problem occured while the developement, but actually it has nothing to do with the game it self.

I have a method ('resize' in a subclass) in my Code which calls the equivalent method in it's super class ('resize' of the superclass).

- Expected Behaviour: Super-resize calls Super-do_rotozoom
- What happend: Super-resize called Sub-do_rotozoom

Here is a code Example:

Subclass:

```
def do_rotozoom(self):
    # do rotozoom stuff of subclass
def resize(self,factor):
    super().resize(factor)
    self.do_rotozoom()
```

Superclass:

```
def do_rotozoom(self):
    #do rotozoom stuff of superclass
def resize(self,factor):
    self.factor = factor
    self.do_rotozoom()
```

I found a workaround which involved calling `super().do_rotozoom()` in the Subclass method `do_rotozoom()` which then was called by the `super().resize()`. I also found out, that I could in this case remove the line `self.do_rotozoom()`.

In this case it was a pretty easy fix, but what would I do in a more complex scenario, for example, if I need to call the method `do_rotozoom()` with other variables in the superclass than I do in the subclass/another specific implementation? In other words, how am I able to select which method I want to use in a specific context?

Normaly you are only able to reach the super-methods from the subclass, but no super-methods (not of it's superclass but it's own methods) from the superclass.

I have not found a better title... :D

Comment: "Method" is spelled with one "e".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very definition of a subclass is that it inherits everything from the superclass *except* the methods and attributes it overrides.

A subclass can refer to its superclass and its method implementations with `super()`, like you already do in your example.

Either don't override `do_rotozoom`, or refer to the superclass method with `super().do_rotozoom()` where that's the behavior you require.

Answer (score 1):

Developers tend to prefer Composition over inheritance , it's much more manageable .

what i advise you to do is to include an instance of your superclass in you subclass and use it whenever you want to .

Comment: I knew about Composition, but I am still at the beginning of my developement in Computer Science, so I am not very familiar with using Patterns. Your Point my be right, but I does not help in my case.